# Core Data NSFetchedResultsController code shortenning

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, magicalrecord, nsfetchedresultscontroller

So im quite new to Core Data and have decided to use Magical Record to reduce LOC.

In my first view, i have a List of Companies and each company has N amount of users

Currently, ive managed to get everything to work just fine, but my code is ridiculously long.

What i want to do is shorten the code, because i KNOW i can, im just not sure how to.

If you look at the code below, you will see a common line used when calling NSFetchedResultsController

```
[self.fetchedResultsController.sections[0]objects]
```

Is there a way to reduce this so i dont have to access index 0 of NSFRC?
Can i do something like

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [self.fetchedResultsController.sections[0]objects]
```

Thanks for your time

**Update:**
I guess i can just get an array from the fetched results controller and use that?

```
NSArray *companies = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.fetchedResultsController.sections[0]objects]];
```

Would my objects still keep the same memory address?

```
#pragma mark Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    // Set up the fetched results controller if needed.
    if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {

        self.fetchedResultsController = [Company MR_fetchAllSortedBy:nil ascending:YES withPredicate:nil groupBy:nil delegate:self inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

#pragma mark - Table View Data Source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController.sections[0]objects] count];
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *string = [[[self.fetchedResultsController.sections[0]objects]objectAtIndex:section]title];
    return string;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [[[[[self.fetchedResultsController.sections[0]objects]objectAtIndex:section]users] allObjects] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell_identifier";
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]  forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    TableViewCell *cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UserProfile *user = [[[[[self.fetchedResultsController.sections[0] objects]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] users] allObjects]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.text = user.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = user.email;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just use

```
-[self.fetchedResults objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

you'll get a big reduction in the data access code you've got here already.

also, don't do this:

```
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]  forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. Generally, do that in viewDidLoad: or some other initialization method.

And, also, I'd personally use the -[NSArray lastObject] or -[NSArray firstObject] methods. These methods will return nil if there are not objects in the array, rather than crashing because of an array index out of bounds exception.